# IPv6 Multicast vs Unicast

Tags: ethernet, ipv6, multicast

I'm currently learning IPv6 and they mentioned broadcast is gone in IPv6 and replaced with multicast and unicast.

Are there some situations where multicast or unicast is better over the other in setups?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

"broadcast" was replaced with more specific multicast methods.  All-station-broadcast would become a huge mess given the available size of IPv6 LANs -- imagine thousands of nodes broadcasting ARPs looking for each other. (it falls apart in IPv4 already)  Multicast Neighbor Discovery limits who hears the requests and answers, in a network with multicast aware hardware.

And there are specific link-local addresses to speak to everyone on the link in the same manner as IPv4 broadcast, without using globally routable addresses.

Comment: I'd say the optimization was misguided and resulted in broken solution. Broadcast in practice in LANs rarely is problematic. However allowing clients to arbitrarily create multicast groups that all switches need to track (in software, with states) is very easy to abuse accidentally or purposely. Broadcasting was stateless, simple to do in HW. Tracking essentially 1:source multicast group is complex and scales very poorly.

Comment: I see you've never been on a large LAN.  IPv6 doesn't change the multicast landscape; everything you complain about, IPv4 hosts have been capable of doing for *years*. All the switches I know of doing multicast filtering do it entirely in hardware -- mgmt only does IGMP processing.

Comment: Even newest Cisco and Juniper gear snoop in software and populate the tables in software + HW. After snooped, forwarding is blocked/accepted in HW. But there are finite amount of entries in HW, much less than maximum possible amount of groups. So attacker in LAN can congest your snooping and can congest your tables. Of course you can opt out from limited-mcast, and just don't snoop in L2 behaving like normal bcast everything, which is what most do, since the alternative/designed goal of only sending to interests hosts scales poorly.

Comment: You might be interested to read more in-depth why this is an issue from http://www.nanog.org/sites/default/files/tues.general.wheeler.neighbor.12.pdf

Comment: I'll say it again... An "attacker" can cause the same mess in an IPv4 ONLY network. IPv6 doesn't magically make multicast "broken" -- 'tho it does expose the very limited nature of IPv4 centric multicast hardware.

Comment: Comment was about the IPv6 optimization of removing broadcasting from neighbor resolution which is unscalable and thus broken, multicast itself is no more or less than in IPv4. If you turn the optimization off (and instead broadcast neighbor resolution) then situation is same as in IPv4.

Comment: You're *assuming* it's broken because it's going to flood multicast tables. While possible (even w/v4), it's not been shown to be a valid argument. And it won't be for "designed for IPv6" gear. (There's a lot of stupid in IPv6, multicast ND is at the bottom of the list, if at all)

Comment: In IPv4 getting mcast groups filled is atypical and worst case scenario is mcast stops working. In IPv6 you might easily accidentally fill your mcast groups, and worst case scenario is network stops working. And problem you're trying to fix with all this complexity is to remove trivial amount of ARP packets, which we've clearly shown over the years with IPV4 it is not a problem.

Comment: History has proven it's a **small** problem. IPv6's dependence on multicast coupled with traditionally small mcast tables will be a *bigger* problem, but there are ways to address it.

Answer (score 4):

There is so much different multicast possible in IPv6... are you talking about multicast traffic (for streaming) or generic multicasts?

FF:: is the multicast range....

FF02:: is Link Local scope, with FF02::1 being the equivalent of the Broadcast Address of a subnet in IPv4
FF02::2 is Link Local, All routers
FF05:: is Site Local, again ::1 for All Node, ::2 for All Routers...

Basically, IPv6 multicasr permits a better targetting of many types of traffic.

Now, for Using Multicast for streaming, it's a lot like in IPv4, with PIM Sparse Mode (no more Dense Mode), MLD (replacing IGMP), Rendez-Vous Points, etc.  There are differences, but not as much as replacing Broadcasts by Scoped Multicasts

Answer (score 2):

When a node issues a broadcast packet, the packet is replicated to all other hosts on the medium or subnet.  So if you have a 32 port switch, and one node issues a broadcast, it goes out each of the 32 ports.  This takes away potential bandwidth from everyone else, especially if it is overused.

Multicast requires that interested parties "subscribe" to a multicaster.  Multicasted traffic only replicates to previously identified subscribed parties, so there is less bandwidth consumed by unwanted traffic.

So multicast is really the better way to go if it is possible and supported by the software and hardware.